# Selecting Tab on TabControl using listbox selected Index

Tags: c#, tabs, listbox, tabcontrol, indexof

I am currently using a tabControl and a listbox independantly of each other.

The tab control has 5 pages on it.
The Listbox has the list of the 5 page titles.

Edit:
I am essentially trying to set the select page of the FundNavigator to be the same as the one selected in the Listbox. So if item number 3 in the list box is selected then I want tab number 3 to be displayed as the selected page.

I want to get it so when you select one of the page titles in the ListBox, it will switch to that tab in the TabControl. I had tried a couple of way, this felt the closest:

```
    public void LoadMatchingTab()
    {
        listIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        FundNavigator.SelectedIndex = FundNavigator.Pages.IndexOf(listIndex);
    }

    private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMatchingTab();
    }
```

With this I am gettinf an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` though andit says

> "index out of range. Parameter Name: value"

Could somebody help me fix this problem?

Comment: What is `FundNavigator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FundNavigator.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex` ?

Comment: Sorry, i have been trying a lot of stuff and my brain is a bit frazzled haha. Just trying to set the select page of the FundNavigator to be the same as the one selected in the Listbox.
So if item number 3 in the list box is selected then I want tab number 3 to be displayed as the selected page.

Comment: Yes, in that case you'd use the code above. If your SelectedIndex's of your FundNavigator are equal to the items in the ListBox, this would work.